# Select latest version from version range in Maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>[1.19.0,2.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any goal in maven which help me always select latest version i.e. 2.0 from above range explicitly and use it.

I am using maven 3.6.

Help appreciated

Comment: Given that Google HTTP Client [hasn't released a 2.0 version yet](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:google-http-client), I presume that this is just an example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your range does NOT include the version `2.0` because it is an open range (to include the version `2.0`, you would need to write `[1.19.0,2.0]`).

Secondly, you can resolve version ranges with the versions maven plugin:

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/resolve-ranges-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in vanilla Maven, just by specifying a version pattern.

To achieve this, you could use the [versions maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-next-releases-mojo.html). It allows you to provide a list of dependencies that should always use the latest version.

Your use case is more or less [described in the documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/advancing-dependency-versions.html).

Alternatively, you could consider using a higher-level tool like [dependabot](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/about-dependabot-version-updates). This would have the benefit of making this part of your CI process, rather than just a step in the application build, and orchestrate this behaviour across other technologies you might be using in your project.